# Generic c++ project in Qt creator - No rule to make target

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qt-creator

I am trying to import a generic project into Qt creator by following [this tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-project-generic.html#specifying-include-paths).
The project has its Makefile which builds multiple separate executables.

Running `make all` in the root directory of the project builds everything correctly.

The project has been imported into Qt creator and the sources show no errors regarding includes. When I press build, i get the error `No rule to make target`all'.  Stop.` As if the Makefile is non existent.

Where is Qt creator looking for the Makefile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case the problem was with the custom build directory in the Build Settings.
Qt creator was searching for the Makefile in the build directory.

When using Qt creatror for Qt projects, I've usually set the build directory to something custom but this isn't sensible here :)